Getting "property id does not support filtering" error while calling Microsoft GraphAPI
I have a list which contains same subject name(meeting name),so wanted to get transcript of both the meetings.
I have below list of subjects :
[
  {
    "subject": "test meeting",
    "id": "AAMkAGRhMzUyMDAxLTYwNGItNGQ1MS1iOTc2LWRiMTVjZGY4ZjdiNgBGAAAAAADO8bPz9-Bl2x4unuBwBsGF5gHPoJQ58zNlatWZK2AAAAAAENAABsGF5gHPoJQ58zNlatWZK2AAR9ytDUAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2024-06-03T05:02:47.9949616Z"
  },
  {
    "subject": "test meeting",
    "id": "AAMkAGRhMzUyMDAxLTYwNGItNGQ1MS1iOTc2LWRiMTVjZGY4ZjdiNgBGAAAAAADO8bPz9-Bl2x4unuBwBsGF5gHPoJQ58zNlatWZK2AAAAAAENAABsGF5gHPoJQ58zNlatWZK2AAR9ytDVAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2024-06-03T05:57:07.5735539Z"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Daily Stand Up",
    "id": "AAMkAGRhMzUyMDAxLTYwNGItNGQ1MS1iOTc2LWRiMTVjZGY4ZjdiNgFRAAgI3INgHJ5AAEYAAAAAzvGz8-wZdseLp7gcAbBheYBz6CUOfMzZWrVmStgAAAAABDQAAbBheYBz6CUOfMzZWrVmStgAEeeHd2QAAEA==",
    "createdDateTime": "2024-05-24T17:00:55.7766826Z"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Team Meeting",
    "id": "AAMkAGRhMzUyMDAxLTYwNGItNGQ1MS1iOTc2LWRiMTVjZGY4ZjdiNgFRAAgI3INgHJ5AAEYAAAAAzvGz8-wZdseLp7gcAbBheYBz6CUOfMzZWrVmStgAAAAABDQAAbBheYBz6CUOfMzZWrVmStgACvb2TTQAAEA==",
    "createdDateTime": "2022-07-28T20:41:01.424176Z"
  },
  {
    "subject": "FILL INTERVALS",
    "id": "AAMkAGRhMzUyMDAxLTYwNGItNGQ1MS1iOTc2LWRiMTVjZGY4ZjdiNgFRAAgI3INgHJ5AAEYAAAAAzvGz8-wZdseLp7gcAbBheYBz6CUOfMzZWrVmStgAAAAABDQAAbBheYBz6CUOfMzZWrVmStgABLSTaCAAAEA==",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-11-25T05:22:56.9312467Z"
  }
]

I have a method to call GraphAPI :
def get_meeting_data_filter_on_subject_and_id(access_token, start_date_ms_graph, end_date_ms_graph, subject_filter,selected_id):
    endpoint = endpoint = f"/me/calendarview?startdatetime={start_date_ms_graph}&enddatetime={end_date_ms_graph}&$count=true&$filter=isCancelled ne true and id eq '{selected_id}'"
    meeting_data = call_graph_api(access_token, endpoint)
    return meeting_data

but on calling above GraphAPI , getting below error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "The property 'id' does not support filtering."
  }

As you can see, in the list there are 2 subjects having same name, So I want to filter above used GraphAPI based on ID to get different response for different meeting or subject, but getting error.
Any help will be thankful.

If you know the event id which is a primary and unique key, you can call directly the endpoint:
GET /me/events/{selected_id}

With the knowledge of event id, filtering doesn't make sense.

I made the changes which you said. Now suppose I have a daily meetings then How can we get meeting details of a particular day. Just want to know is selected_id will change everyday or have to filter out for particular day?

If I understand correctly, you are displaying list of events for a particular day. Then user can select one event to see more details? In that case you need two methods: List of events: /me/calendarview?startdatetime={start_date_ms_graph}&enddatetime={end_date_ms_graph}&$count=true&$filter=isCancelled ne true and to display details of selected event: me/events/{selected_id}
